# Class attribute as a jquery selector when css class already exists

Tags: jquery

I understand that selecting by the `class` attribute in jquery is one of the most performant ways of selecting elements. We apply the `class` attribute on all elements to represent the CSS style. I'd like to select a subset of these elements using jquery class selector.

So, should I be applying multiple styles to the element - one to represent the css style and the other on solely for jquery selection purposes?

Comment: This what I do to group the elements that need to use the same jQuery event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple classes to describe different "information" of an element. For example Wordpress does that with the "body" element, it assigns classes that represent the browser type etc.

Another way to do that is to assign a class / id to a parent of the elements you want to select, such that you can do this:

```
jQuery('#parent_of_group').find('.class_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting elements by `class` attribute value certainly is **not** "one of the most performant ways" to select an element.  On the contrary: jQuery's [Sizzle is *very slow*](http://jsperf.com/sizzle-is-slow/2) by comparison, especially when a class simple selector is involved.

Instead, one of the more efficient ways to select an element is by ID.  You should do this if there is only one relevant element, as IDs must be unique in a document.  It would probably be best then if you used the now-ubiquitous `document.getElementById()` method, and only created a jQuery object if it is absolutely necessary.

But you should **check first whether it is *necessary* to select elements at all**.  DOM APIs have several other, more compatible entry points to refer to an element object, among them `this` (in event-handler attribute values and event listeners), `event` (in event-handler attribute values), and [element collections and node lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference).  [Event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) also is ubiquitous by now, although [not all events bubble in all implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events).

Answer (score 0):

Elements can have multiple classes

```
class="firstClass secondClass thirdClass"
```

..if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand it correctly, you want to select a subset of elements with a certain class (`class1`), again filtered by another class (`class2`)?

```
jQuery('.class1.class2');
// or
jQuery('.class1').filter('.class2');
```